# Getting a bug only on page refresh

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, browser-cache

Right now I have a javascript bug on one of my pages that only occurs after I refresh the page. If I click on a link to go to the page, the bug never appears. I thought the issue had something to do with the browser cache so I put `<meta http-equiv="PRAGMA" content="NO-CACHE">` in the head section of the `_layout.cshtml` view. Still no dice.

I simply want the problem to go away using the least amount of effort possible, so how can I ensure that a page refresh (using F5 or the browser button) acts like a page load?

Edit:

So after taking a suggestion in the comments to do a reload without caching, apparently it is a browser cache issue. So the parameters of my question have changed. I want to be able to disable the cache for one view only. What do I do to make this happen?

Comment: If it's a Javascript bug, can we see the JS?

Comment: A refresh act the same way as an initial page load, except that it may load data from the cache instead. If you clear you cache, does the problem persist? In chrome you can use Ctrl + Shift + R to reload the page ignoring the cache, do you get the same problem then?

Comment: @SomeKittens no you can't you have to imagine :)

Comment: I've seen problems like this that are caused by the order in which files load. Sometimes, either on initial load or refresh, some javascript loads or runs faster than others and a bug appears. But without sharing any code, or even what error you get, I'm not sure how you expect us to help.

Comment: Christofer, the problem doesn't persist when I use ctrl+shift+r. How can I disable the cache?